# Как убрать горизонтальный скролл колесиком мыши при perspective (css)?

Tags: css, css3, css-animation, parallax

Как убрать горизонтальный скролл зажатым колесиком мыши на блоке у которого задано свойство *perspective*? 
`owerflow-x: hidden` прячет только горизонтальный скроллбар, а вот колесиком все-же можно уйти вправо.
Пример:

[image: aa08e27523264d14b47e44d872907b96.png]

Сам сайт, если есть желание попробовать самому:
[instagram-promo.webflow.io](http://instagram-promo.webflow.io)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью javascript отключить нажатие колёсиком

```js
$(function() {
  $('div').mousedown(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 2){
      return false;
    };
  });
});
```

```css
div {width:150px;height:150px;overflow:hidden}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr></div>
```

Comment: А можно отследить движение с зажатым колесиком вправо? И уже его отключить?

Comment: @ВячеславЯшников, поищите в интернете. Есть много страниц где рассказано, как реализовываются функции с колёсиком

Comment: @ВячеславЯшников, или задавайте ещё один вопрос и я на него отвечу